# Rails and JQuery selecting a random item from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I feel like I'm pretty close here trying to select a random image from my assets path and set it as the background.

```
birds = ['birdonbranch.jpeg', 'birdsfighting.jpg', 'cranes.jpg', 'rainbowbird.jpeg', 'whitebird.jpeg'];
birdSample = birds.sample
$("html").css({"background-image":"url(" + "<%= asset_path(" + birdSample + ") %>" + ")"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the first two lines in <%...%>

But you might look into http://reactrb.org which allows you to develop in straight Ruby.   Much less confusing IMHO

Comment: I would but the assignment limits us to certain languages.  This is above what they're asking, just something I was interested in trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a `.js.erb` file, your ruby code should be wrapped in `<% %>`.

```
<% 
  birds = ['birdonbranch.jpeg', 'birdsfighting.jpg', 'cranes.jpg', 'rainbowbird.jpeg', 'whitebird.jpeg'];
  birdSample = birds.sample
%>

$("html").css({
  "background-image": url("<%= asset_path(birdSample) %>")
});
```

Comment: I've got this sort of working with what you posted.  It's giving me the value in the browser of url("NaN").  I can't believe I forgot to wrap my ruby code haha.

Comment: I didn't test the code, but maybe you're missing the `/images` path, since `asset_path` returns the path to the `assets` folder, and not directly to `assets/images`.